# React TypeScript/Firebase -Property '_tokenResponse' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

I am new at typescript and i am trying to convert my react project to typescript.
I am creating a user through firebase but it gives me this error **Property '_tokenResponse' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'.** How do i solve this?

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,values.email,values.password)
                       .then((userCredential) => {
                        console.log(userCredential);
                        setSubmitting(false);
                        authContext.logIn(userCredential._tokenResponse.idToken);
                        navigate('/');
                      }).catch((err)=>{
                        setError(err.message);
                      })
```

The entire code for authContext

````
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const AuthContext=React.createContext({
    token:'',
    isLoggedIn:false,
    logIn:(token:string)=>{},
    logOut:()=>{},
});

export const AuthContextProvider:React.FC=(props)=>{
    const initialToken=localStorage.getItem('token')??'';
    const [token,setToken]=useState(initialToken);

    const userIsLoggedIn=!!token;
    //console.log(userIsLoggedIn);

    const loginHandler=(token:string)=>{
       // console.log(token);
        setToken(token);
        localStorage.setItem('token',token);
    }

    const logoutHandler=()=>{
        setToken('');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }

    const contextValue={
        token:token,
        isLoggedIn:userIsLoggedIn,
        logIn:loginHandler,
        logOut:logoutHandler
    };

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAuth=()=>{
    const context = React.useContext(AuthContext)
    if (context === undefined) {
      throw new Error('useAuth must be used within a AuthContextProvider')
    }
    return context
  }

export default AuthContext;```
````

Comment: Can you give some more context  about `authContext.logIn` ?

Comment: i have edited the question and added to it. Please take a look

Comment: Why are you trying to store the token? The SDK is handling it for you. The `_` means that an element should be protected (by naming convention), that's why you are not getting it in the type definition, or at least that's what seems to me, also by looking at the documentation.

Comment: so that the user remains logged in on refresh too (the state persists). should i not be doing it?

Comment: @H.b, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Firebase JavaScript SDK, you don't need to handle tokens by yourself, they are handled under the hood by the SDK itself.

As you can read here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailand

> On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application

To keep your user logged in when you close the page, check the persistence section here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence

and also here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence

So basically, just don't try to read the token, that is supposed to be protected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#.UserCredential) doesn't have a uid(_tokenResponse) property. My best guess is that you're looking for user.user.uid.

```
const user = userCredential.user;
```

Comment: i am still getting the error. This error occurred after i added typescript to the file so i think it has something to do with typescript

Comment: did u tried adding :any as data type